# What is the difference between "a{1}" and "a" in regex?

Tags: regex

Some string was matched with the following `regex

```
([0-9]\s+){1}
```

Why did author use `{1}` in the end of regex?

Can I safely remove it?

Comment: might be a failed attempt to match `"a"` but not `"aa"`

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there is no difference at all. Possibly it was left over from tweaks made while the regex was being built and tested.

Comment: Downvoter: I would appreciate a comment so that I can improve the answer.

Comment: Thank you. I hope it was left over.

Answer (score 2):

`{1}` limits the regex match to only one integer or space, in your example.

Comment: I am sure: if i have "0   1    2  " input string - there is no difference if I have {1} or no, I get three (3) matches "0___", "1___", "2__".

Comment: The regex will only match 1 integer / space. So if you have something like 1a, it won't match that.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably a leftover from debugging/writing the query when the author experimented with `{1,2}` or so.

Yes, you can remove it.

Answer (score 0):

if it is the result of an interpreted code (log/debug coming from script for exemple) the 1 could be the value of a variable.
If it is directly in a script, {1} is the default behavior so it is the same (but take longer to work due to extra interpreation to make by the parser)